# Variable in Xpath is not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, xpath

```
#driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="groups"]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/button').click()
i = 5
gPath1 = str("\'//div[@id=\"groups\"]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[")
gPath2 = str(i)
gPath3 = str("]/div/div/button\'")
gPath = gPath1 + gPath2 + gPath3

driver.find_element_by_xpath(gPath).click()
```

I'm getting InvalidSelectorException error while using variable, but when i use the commented line it is working fine. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `\'` from the beginning and from the end. So that your code would look like:

```
gPath1 = str("//div[@id=\"groups\"]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[")
gPath2 = str(i)
gPath3 = str("]/div/div/button")
gPath = gPath1 + gPath2 + gPath3

driver.find_element_by_xpath(gPath).click()
```